# Event calender- PHP

Tags: php

Could somebody please help me these 2 questions, as I am having a hard time implementing this?

I am building an event calender with php, javascript, html and css using the help of a tutorial.

The calender highlights the current day as red. When a booking has been made, the day of which the booking is made, turns navy.

Question 1

This was a success, when the insert form was attached to the calender page. But due to some bizarre working of the code, the form ends up becoming designed in the same manner as the calender. So for example, if the month row is coloured yellow and the day row is colored grey, then for some reason, the form with the first row becomes yellow and the second row becomes grey. Essentially, the form style is weirdly attached to the calender style. How can I stop this from happening?

Question 2

The second query, is that in order to a avoid the above, I tried redirecting the user to the event form on a separate page. While the event was successfully added to the database, when I go back to the calender page, the booking date is not turned navy as before. I need the date to turn navy again as before and also display the booking details, as question 1 did successfully.

As you can tell, I am really stuck here, and need some help (I would really love to implement the second question/scenario) but the first one is also fine for me. Please find the code below for each question. Thank you so much any help you can provide.

Question 1

calender.php

```
 <?php
//These are required to connect to the database
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'calender');

//This variable is used for displaying error
$error="Cannot connect";

//Connect to the database
$dbconnection=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or     die($error);
mysqli_select_db($dbconnection,"calender") or die($error);
?>

<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
//This function represents the previous button on the calender
function goPreviousMonth(month, year){ 
if (month == 1) { 
--year; 
month = 13; 
} 
--month
var monthstring=""+month+"";
var monthlength=monthstring.length;
if(monthlength<=1){
monthstring="0"+monthstring;
}
//This creates the URL to state the month and year.
document.location.href = "<?php     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year; 
} 

//This function represents the next button on the calender
function goNextMonth(month, year){ 
if (month == 12){ 
++year; 
month = 0; 
} 
++month
var monthstring=""+month+"";
var monthlength=monthstring.length;
if(monthlength<=1){
    monthstring="0"+monthstring;
}
//This creates the URL to state the month and year.
document.location.href = "<?php     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year; 
} 
</script> 
</head> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calenderfakestyle.css">


<body> 

<?php 
//Check the URL to see if the user has passed a variable

//This is used to check if day has a passing variable 
if (isset ($_GET['day'])){ 
//If true, then get the day from the URL
$day = $_GET['day']; 
}else{ 
$day = date ("d");
} 

//The is used to check if month has a passing variable
if (isset ($_GET['month'])){ 
//If true, then get the month from the URL
 $month = $_GET['month']; 
 }else{ 
 $month = date ("n"); 
 } 

//The is used to check if month has a passing variable
if (isset ($_GET['year'])){ 
//If true, then get the year from the URL
 $year = $_GET['year']; 
 }else{ 
 $year = date ("Y"); 
 } 

 //The calender variables

 //This stores day, month and year variables within a timestamp
 $currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day"); 

 //This gets the current month name 
 $monthName = date("F", $currentTimeStamp); 

 //This determines how many days there are in the current month 
 $numDays = date("t", $currentTimeStamp); 

 //This variable is used to count cells in the loop later
 $counter = 0; 
 ?> 

 <?php
 //This code must be below the date variable
 if(isset($_GET['add'])){
     $title=$_POST['txttitle'];
     $detail=$_POST['txtdetail'];

     $eventdate=$month."/".$day."/".$year;

     $sqlinsert="insert into booking (title,detail,event_date,date_added)     values ('".$title."','".$detail."','".$eventdate."',now())";
     $resultinsert=mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlinsert);
     if($resultinsert){
         echo "Event was successfully added";
     }else{
         echo "Event was not added";
     }
 }


 ?>
 <table border='1'> 
    <tr> <td> <input class="previousbutton" type='button' value='<'     name='previousbutton' onClick="goPreviousMonth (<?php echo     $month.",".$year?>)"> </td> 
         <td colspan='5'> <span class="title"> <?php echo $monthName."     ".$year; ?> </span> </td> 
         <td> <input class="nextbutton"  type='button' value='>'     name='nextbutton' onClick="goNextMonth (<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)">     </td> 
    </tr> 

 <tr> 
    <td>Sun</td> 
    <td>Mon</td> 
    <td>Tue</td> 
    <td>Wed</td> 
    <td>Thu</td> 
    <td>Fri</td> 
    <td>Sat</td> 
 </tr> <?php echo "<tr>"; 

 //This is used to loop from 1 to the number of days in the month
 for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++, $counter++){

 //This is a timestamp for each day in the loop
 $timeStamp = strtotime ("$year-$month-$i"); 

//This checks if if it is the first day
if($i == 1){ 
    //This determines which day for the first date of the month
    $firstDay = date ("w", $timeStamp);
    //This loop is used to make a blank cell if it is not the first day
    for ($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++){ 
    //Blank space 
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; 
     } 
   } 
    //This checks to see if the day is on the last column. If so, a new     row will be made.
    if($counter % 7 == 0 ){     
    echo "<tr></tr>"; 
 } 
$monthstring=$month;
$monthlength=strlen($monthstring);
$daystring=$i;
$daylength=strlen($daystring);
if($monthlength<=1){
$monthstring="0".$monthstring;  
}
if($daylength<=1){
    $daystring="0".$daystring;
}
$todaysDate=date("m/d/Y");
$dateToCompare=$monthstring. '/' . $daystring . '/' . $year;
echo "<td align='center' ";
if($todaysDate==$dateToCompare){
echo "class='today'";   
}else{
    $sqlCount="select * from booking where     event_date='".$dateToCompare."'";
    $noOfEvent= mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlCount));
    if($noOfEvent>=1){
        echo "class='event'";
    }
}
echo "><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&    day=".$daystring."&year=".$year."&v=true'>".$i."</a></td>";
 } 
 echo "</tr>"; 
 ?> 
 </table> 

 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['v'])){
     echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$month."&    day=".$day."&year=".$year."&v=true&f=true'>Add Event</a>";
     if(isset($_GET['f'])){
         include("eventform.php");
     }
     $sqlEvent="select * from booking where     event_date='".$month."/".$day."/".$year."'";
     $resultEvents=mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlEvent);
     echo "<hr>";
     while($events=mysqli_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
     echo "Title : ".$events['title']."<br>"; 
     echo "Detail : ".$events['detail']."<br>";
     }
 }
 ?>

 </body> 
 </html>
```

eventform.php

```
<form name='eventform' method='POST' action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];     ?>?month=<?php echo $month;?>&day=<?php echo $day;?>&year=<?php echo     $year;?>&v=true&add=true">

<table width='400px'>
    <tr>
        <td width='150px'>Title</td>
        <td width='250px'><input type='text' name='txttitle'> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width='150px'>Detail</td>
        <td width='250px'> <textarea name='txtdetail'> </textarea> </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td td colspan='2'align='center'> <input type='submit' name='btnadd'     value='Add Event'> </td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Question 2

calender.php

```
         <?php
        //These are required to connect to the database
        DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
        DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
        DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
        DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'calender');

    //This variable is used for displaying error
    $error="Cannot connect";

//Connect to the database
$dbconnection=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or     die($error);
mysqli_select_db($dbconnection,"calender") or die($error);
ob_start();
?>

<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
//This function represents the previous button on the calender
function goPreviousMonth(month, year){ 
if (month == 1) { 
--year; 
month = 13; 
} 
--month
var monthstring=""+month+"";
var monthlength=monthstring.length;
if(monthlength<=1){
    monthstring="0"+monthstring;
}
//This creates the URL to state the month and year.
document.location.href = "<?php     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year; 
} 

//This function represents the next button on the calender
function goNextMonth(month, year){ 
if (month == 12){ 
++year; 
month = 0; 
} 
++month
var monthstring=""+month+"";
var monthlength=monthstring.length;
if(monthlength<=1){
    monthstring="0"+monthstring;
}
//This creates the URL to state the month and year.
document.location.href = "<?php     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year; 
} 
</script> 
</head> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calenderfakestyle.css">


<body> 

<?php 
//Check the URL to see if the user has passed a variable

//This is used to check if day has a passing variable 
if (isset ($_GET['day'])){ 
//If true, then get the day from the URL
$day = $_GET['day']; 
}else{ 
$day = date ("d");
} 

//The is used to check if month has a passing variable
if (isset ($_GET['month'])){ 
//If true, then get the month from the URL
 $month = $_GET['month']; 
 }else{ 
 $month = date ("n"); 
 } 

//The is used to check if month has a passing variable
if (isset ($_GET['year'])){ 
//If true, then get the year from the URL
 $year = $_GET['year']; 
 }else{ 
 $year = date ("Y"); 
 } 

 //The calender variables

 //This stores day, month and year variables within a timestamp
 $currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day"); 

 //This gets the current month name 
 $monthName = date("F", $currentTimeStamp); 

 //This determines how many days there are in the current month 
 $numDays = date("t", $currentTimeStamp); 

 //This variable is used to count cells in the loop later
 $counter = 0; 
 ?> 

 <?php
 //This code must be below the date variable
 if(isset($_GET['add'])){
     $title=$_POST['txttitle'];
     $detail=$_POST['txtdetail'];

     $eventdate=$month."/".$day."/".$year;

     $sqlinsert="insert into booking (title,detail,event_date,date_added)     values ('".$title."','".$detail."','".$eventdate."',now())";
     $resultinsert=mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlinsert);
     if($resultinsert){
         echo "Event was successfully added";
     }else{
         echo "Event was not added";
     }
 }


 ?>
 <table border='1'> 
    <tr> <td> <input class="previousbutton" type='button' value='<'     name='previousbutton' onClick="goPreviousMonth (<?php echo     $month.",".$year?>)"> </td> 
         <td colspan='5'> <span class="title"> <?php echo $monthName."     ".$year; ?> </span> </td> 
         <td> <input class="nextbutton"  type='button' value='>'     name='nextbutton' onClick="goNextMonth (<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)">     </td> 
    </tr> 

 <tr> 
    <td>Sun</td> 
    <td>Mon</td> 
    <td>Tue</td> 
    <td>Wed</td> 
    <td>Thu</td> 
    <td>Fri</td> 
    <td>Sat</td> 
 </tr> <?php echo "<tr>"; 

 //This is used to loop from 1 to the number of days in the month
 for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++, $counter++){

 //This is a timestamp for each day in the loop
 $timeStamp = strtotime ("$year-$month-$i"); 

//This checks if if it is the first day
if($i == 1){ 
    //This determines which day for the first date of the month
    $firstDay = date ("w", $timeStamp);
    //This loop is used to make a blank cell if it is not the first day
    for ($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++){ 
    //Blank space 
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; 
    } 
   } 
    //This checks to see if the day is on the last column. If so, a new     row will be made.
    if($counter % 7 == 0 ){     
    echo "<tr></tr>"; 
 } 
$monthstring=$month;
$monthlength=strlen($monthstring);
$daystring=$i;
$daylength=strlen($daystring);
if($monthlength<=1){
$monthstring="0".$monthstring;  
}
if($daylength<=1){
    $daystring="0".$daystring;
}
$todaysDate=date("m/d/Y");
$dateToCompare=$monthstring. '/' . $daystring . '/' . $year;
echo "<td align='center' ";
if($todaysDate==$dateToCompare){
echo "class='today'";   
}else{
    $sqlCount="select * from booking where     event_date='".$dateToCompare."'";
    $noOfEvent= mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlCount));
    if($noOfEvent>=1){
        echo "class='event'";
    }
}
echo "><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&    day=".$daystring."&year=".$year."&v=true'>".$i."</a></td>";
 } 
 echo "</tr>"; 
 ?> 
 </table> 

 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['v'])){
        header("Location:eventform.php");
     if(isset($_GET['f'])){
         include("eventform.php");
     }
     $sqlEvent="select * from booking where     event_date='".$month."/".$day."/".$year."'";
     $resultEvents=mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlEvent);
     echo "<hr>";
     while($events=mysqli_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
     echo "Title : ".$events['title']."<br>"; 
     echo "Detail : ".$events['detail']."<br>";
     }
 }
 ?>




 </body> 
 </html>
```

Eventform.php

```
<?php


DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'calender');

//This variable is used for displaying error
$error="Cannot connect";

//Connect to the database
$dbconnection=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or     die($error);
mysqli_select_db($dbconnection,"calender") or die($error);

//Check the URL to see if the user has passed a variable

//This is used to check if day has a passing variable 
if (isset ($_GET['day'])){ 
//If true, then get the day from the URL
$day = $_GET['day']; 
}else{ 
$day = date ("d");
} 

//The is used to check if month has a passing variable
if (isset ($_GET['month'])){ 
//If true, then get the month from the URL
 $month = $_GET['month']; 
 }else{ 
 $month = date ("n"); 
 } 

//The is used to check if month has a passing variable
if (isset ($_GET['year'])){ 
//If true, then get the year from the URL
 $year = $_GET['year']; 
 }else{ 
 $year = date ("Y"); 
 } 

 //The calender variables

 //This stores day, month and year variables within a timestamp
 $currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day"); 

 //This gets the current month name 
 $monthName = date("F", $currentTimeStamp); 

 //This determines how many days there are in the current month 
 $numDays = date("t", $currentTimeStamp); 

 //This variable is used to count cells in the loop later
 $counter = 0; 


if(isset($_GET['add'])){
     $title=$_POST['txttitle'];
     $detail=$_POST['txtdetail'];

     $eventdate=$month."/".$day."/".$year;

     $sqlinsert="insert into booking (title,detail,event_date,date_added)     values ('".$title."','".$detail."','".$eventdate."',now())";
     $resultinsert=mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlinsert);
     if($resultinsert){
         echo "Event was successfully added";
     }else{
         echo "Event was not added";
      }
 }

?>













<form name='eventform' method='POST' action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];     ?>?month=<?php echo $month;?>&day=<?php echo $day;?>&year=<?php echo     $year;?>&v=true&add=true">

<table width='400px'>
    <tr>
        <td width='150px'>Title</td>
        <td width='250px'><input type='text' name='txttitle'> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width='150px'>Detail</td>
        <td width='250px'> <textarea name='txtdetail'> </textarea> </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td td colspan='2'align='center'> <input type='submit' name='btnadd'     value='Add Event'> </td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

CSS stylesheet for both questions:

```
table {
position: absolute;
width: 700px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -350px;
margin-top:-30px;
text-align: center; 
border-collapse: collapse;
font-size: 20px;
}

table tr td a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width:100%;
padding: 20% 0;
}

td {
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
background-color: white;
}

a:link {
    color: black;
}

a:visited {
    color: black;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: purple;
}

.previousbutton{
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
border: none;
background-color: blue;
cursor: pointer;
font-size:20px;
}

.previousbutton:hover{
background-color: #blue;
}

.nextbutton{
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
border: none;
background-color: blue;
cursor: pointer;
font-size:20px;
}

.nextbutton:hover{
background-color: #7FFFD4;
}

.today {
    background-color: red;
}

.event {
    background-color: navy;
}

tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2){
    background-color: yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1n){
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.title {
    color:black;    
}
```

The database contains the following fields:

```
ID
title
detail
event_date
date_added
```

Comment: One question at a time; it's now too broad.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I'm new here. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: To everyone reading this: my apologies for the errors and inconsistencies with the code. I have updated the codes for both question 1 and 2. I appreciate all the help and response. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: your CSS is too generic, so all table related elements end up with the same style.

Ex. you define

```
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2){
    background-color: yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1n){
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

This **applies to ALL tr elements in ALL tables**.

If you want to apply it only to the calendar table, you could add a class name to the tr in the calendar (ex caltr), and modify your css to specify tr.caltr.  Then the tr in the form would not apply this style.

You use that mechanism for .today.  Only td with class="today" will end up being red, so apply the same thing to your tr elements.

Question 2: once you fix question 1, is there a need for question 2 anymore?  Seems like not.

### Examples:

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Table1</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr class="table1"><th>Cell1</th><th>Cell2</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table1"><td>value1-1</td><td>Value1-2</td></tr>
                <tr class="table1"><td>value2-1</td><td>Value2-2</td></tr>
                <tr class="table1"><td>value3-1</td><td>Value3-2</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h1>Table2</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Cell1</th><th>Cell2</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>value1-1</td><td>Value1-2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>value2-1</td><td>Value2-2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>value3-1</td><td>Value3-2</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

test2.css

```
/* TEST */
tr.table1:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2){
    background-color: yellow;
}

tr.table1:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1n){
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

Using this you will get:

[image]

See how the tr in the two tables are separate?  You use the class="" attribute to differentiate between the two.  You must edit your HTML and your CSS to match.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it seems the code I posted is not working. I will need to repost this question with the correct code. My apologies to anyone bothered by the code.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. I have updated the code above, if you would like to test. Thanks again.

Comment: Updated an example of how to do it, using classes to differentiate between TR inside TABLE.